# How to Create Nested Builder Based DSLs on Groovy using FactoryBuilderSupport

Tags: groovy, dsl, builder

I want to create a nested builder. Something like:

```
meta('JSON') {
   // JSON content using JSON Builder in this case
}
content('HTML') {
   // HTML content using MarkupTemplateEngine in this case
}
```

I don't want to have

```
JsonBuilder builder = new JsonBuilder()
builder.author {
}
```

or

```
def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder()
builder.html {
}
```

How can initial builder and the nested builder be setup?

---

I have defined the DSL common elements as:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.eclipse.collections.impl.map.mutable.UnifiedMap

@CompileStatic
abstract class DSLElement extends UnifiedMap {
    DSLElement(Map attributes) {
        putAll(attributes)
    }

    getAt(Object key) {
        get(key)
    }

    putAt(Object key, Object value) {
        put(key, value)
    }
}

@CompileStatic
class BaseFactoryBuilder extends FactoryBuilderSupport {
    BaseFactoryBuilder(boolean init = true) {
        super(init)
    }
}

@CompileStatic
class DSLFactoryBuilder
        extends BaseFactoryBuilder
        implements MetaRegistration,
                ContentRegistration,
                TemplateRegistration {

}
```

Individual elements I have defined as:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
import groovy.transform.SelfType

@CompileStatic
@InheritConstructors
class Meta extends DSLElement {}

@CompileStatic
class MetaFactory extends AbstractFactory {
    boolean isLeaf() {
        return false
    }

    Object newInstance(FactoryBuilderSupport builder, Object name, Object value, Map attributes)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return new Meta(attributes)
    }
}

@SelfType(DSLFactoryBuilder)
@CompileStatic
trait MetaRegistration {
    registerMeta() {
        registerFactory("meta", new MetaFactory())
    }
}
```

and

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
import groovy.transform.SelfType

@CompileStatic
@InheritConstructors
class Content extends DSLElement {
}

@CompileStatic
class ContentFactory extends AbstractFactory {
    boolean isLeaf() {
        return false
    }

    Object newInstance(FactoryBuilderSupport builder, Object name, Object value, Map attributes)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return new Content(attributes)
    }
}

@SelfType(DSLFactoryBuilder)
@CompileStatic
trait ContentRegistration {
    registerMeta() {
        registerFactory("content", new ContentFactory())
    }
}
```

I have not figured you how to do the nesting another builder and the parameter `'JSON'` or `'HTML'`.

I am following the FactoryBuilderSupport example given in: [Groovy for Domain-Specific Languages](https://javabeat.net/groovy-for-domain-specific-languages/)

Answer (score 1):

maybe i did not fully understand the question - it's too long to read and code you provided not runnable (or not full)

i assume you want to achieve this:

```
def html = meta('HTML'){
    person(name:'foo')
}

def json = meta('JSON'){
    person(name:'bar')
}
```

if so, here is a code to implement it

```
String meta(String ctxName, Closure builderBody){
    def builder = null
    def writer = null
    if(ctxName=='HTML'){
        writer=new StringWriter()
        builder=new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
    }else if(ctxName=='JSON'){
        builder=new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
    }
    else throw new RuntimeException("unsupported meta=`$ctxName`")
    
    def result = builder.with(builderBody)
    
    if(ctxName=='HTML'){
        return writer.toString()
    }else if(ctxName=='JSON'){
        return builder.toPrettyString()
    }
}


println meta('HTML'){
    person(name:'foo')
}

println meta('JSON'){
    person(name:'bar')
}
```

result:

```xml
<person name='foo' />
```

```json
{
    "person": {
        "name": "bar"
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. +1 for the effort but this is not what I was looking for. Essentially what I want is if there are 2 or more implementations of FactoryBuilderSupport, e.g., a JSON builder, YAML Builder, Node Builder, MarkupBuilder then how do I create a builder which reuses these builders, My DSL will have parts which are JSON or YAML and HTML (Markup Builder) as some of the nodes, hence one Builder implementation is nested within the nodes of another builder implementation.

Comment: in builders the single value parameter is busy with closure `X{ ... }` and you could have only value parameter. the other parameters - are named passed through map `attributes`. i think you have to use some specific attribute name like this: `X(builder:'JSON') { ... }` in this case you could take it from attribute

Comment: I think we are closer to the solution I was looking for. How do I evoke the *Builder* of the inner DSL within `AbstractFactory.newInstance`? Also what is are the uses for `FactoryBuilderSupport builder, Object name, Object value` parameters. In this case since `Object value` is not the last parameters it might not be the closure. Should I ask a follow-up question on this which gives more space to answer?